# Incorrect count on collection (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-query, discord.js

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but count on db.collection().find() isn't finding the documents, or sometimes, it's apparently finding something even though the collection is completely empty.

Code:

```
module.exports.execute = async (message, args) => {
mongoose.connect(mongoPath, (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (db.collection('Queue').find({userId: message.author.id}).count() > 0) {
        message.channel.send(`You're already in queue, ${message.author}!`);
        console.log("Already in queue");
    } else {
        console.log("Added to queue!");
        db.collection('Queue').insertOne({
            username: message.author.username,
            userId: message.author.id
        });
        message.channel.send(`Added ${message.author.username} to queue!`);
        db.close();
    }
});
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I know, for DynamoDB, this can happen due to the amount of data surpassing the capabilities of the call, so the query finishes without actually analyzing the entire dataset. Give me a minute to research the actual solution for it. I've had to deal with this in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database operation are asynchronous, and returns Promise.

You can use `await`

> The keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result.

https://javascript.info/async-await

Change

```
if (db.collection('Queue').find({userId: message.author.id}).count() > 0) {
```

to

```
mongoose.connect(mongoPath, async (err, db) => {
// ...
const count = await db.collection('Queue').find({userId: message.author.id}).count();

if (count > 0) {
```

Read - https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/promises/

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: @Jonathon Updated check